# Submenu items Gatsby+WordPress headless CMS

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I am having a hard time creating submenu items for my WordPress menu on my Gatsby site. It keeps giving me error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Been researching trying to find a solution for submenu items on my headless WordPress installation. So far I've found [an old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074029/get-wordpress-submenus-in-gatsby-js) but the solution doesn't seem to work when I test. I've also tried to create a separate file and then import it into the page using import but that didn't turn out good either.

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql, StaticQuery, Link } from 'gatsby';

const MainMenu = () => (
  <StaticQuery query={graphql`{
    allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems {
      edges {
        node {
          items {
            title
            object_slug
            url
             wordpress_children {
          title
          object_slug
          url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
      `} render={props => (
      <ul className="menu">
        {
          props.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items.map(item => (
            <li><Link to={`/${item.url}`} key={item.object_slug}>
              {item.title}
            </Link></li>
          ))
        }
        <ul className="submenu">
          {props.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items.wordpress_children.map(subitem => (
            <li><Link to={`/${subitem.url}`} key={subitem.object_slug}>
              {subitem.title}
            </Link></li>
          ))
          }
        </ul>
      </ul >
    )} />
);

export default MainMenu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this. For anyone else looking for a solution to submenu items on a WordPress/Gatsby site this did the trick for me:

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql, Link } from "gatsby"

export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
              name
              items {
                title
                url
                object_slug
                wordpress_children {
                  title
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => {
      return (
        <ul className="menu">
          {data &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0] &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items.map(
              prop => {
                return (
                  <li>
                    <Link
                      to={prop.url}
                      alt={prop.title}
                    >
                      {prop.title}
                    </Link>
                    <ul className="sub-menu">
                      {prop &&
                        prop.wordpress_children &&
                        prop.wordpress_children.map(child => {

                          return (
                            <li> <Link
                              className="dropdown-item"
                              to={child.url}
                              alt={child.title}
                            >
                              {child.title}
                            </Link></li>
                          )
                        })}
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                )
              }
            )}
        </ul>
      )
    }}
  />
)
```

Comment: I think you could clean up that map() over the data by simply saying:
`data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items.map(...` In place of `data &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0] &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items &&
            data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems.edges[0].node.items.map(`